# Using JDK15's JEP 378 text blocks in Tomcat JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, java-15, jep

Sample code:

```
String s = """
test
""";
%>
```

Getting.

> org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass Unsupported target VM [15] requested, using [13]

/usr/local/tomcat/bin/version.sh reports:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.38
JVM Version:    15+36-1562
```

At http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/changelog.html I see:

> Add support for specifying Java 14 (with the value 14) and Java 15 (with the value 15) as the compiler source and/or compiler target for JSP compilation. If used with an ECJ version that does not support these values, a warning will be logged and the latest supported version will used. (markt)

Anyone had any success getting Text Blocks working on non-alpha Tomcat?

Comment: Looks like that change is in `Tomcat 10.0.0-M4`, while you are using 9.0.38

Comment: @JornVernee that is correct.  Tomcat 9 says it supports Java 8 and "later".  I have been unable to have it compile JSPs with Text Blocks.  Tomcat 9 would appear to require a similar change to what was implemented in Tomcat 10 (which is alpha).